# Apollo GraphQL Query works only once. How can I run it again?

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, graphql, apollo

I'm using **Angular 7**, **Apollo Server**, **MongoDB** in my project.
I have a problem.

**Apollo Graphql Query** is running once in the **ngOnInit** function. But as you can see in my code example, I want the query refreshed when the **onPageChanged** function is fired. **OnPageChanged** or when I put my graphQL codes in a different function, the codes never work the second time.
What I need to do to regulate my query at any time. can you help me please.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminAuthorsGQL, Authors } from 'src/generated-models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-authors',
  templateUrl: './admin-authors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-authors.component.scss']
})

export class AdminAuthorsComponent implements OnInit {
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['no', 'image', 'name', 'translator', 'books', 'transactions'];

public table = {
    display: false,
    text: 'table'
  };

public form = {
    display: false,
    text: 'form'
  };

authors$: Observable<Authors.Authors[]>;

pageEvent: PageEvent;

pageSize: number = 25; // default

skip: number = 0;

length = 1000;

pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 50, 100];

isLoadingResults: boolean = false;
isNoDataFound: boolean = false;

constructor(private adminAuthorsGql: AdminAuthorsGQL) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.authors$ = this.adminAuthorsGql
    .watch({ skip: this.skip, limit: this.pageSize })
    .valueChanges.pipe(map(result => result.data.authorsWithPaginate));

    this.isLoadingResults = false;
    this.isNoDataFound = false;
  }

setPageSizeOptions(setPageSizeOptionsInput: string) {
    this.pageSizeOptions = setPageSizeOptionsInput.split(',').map(str => +str);
  }

onPageChanged(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.pageSize = e.pageSize;
    this.authors$ = this.adminAuthorsGql
    .watch({ skip: this.skip, limit: this.pageSize })
    .valueChanges.pipe(
     map(result => result.data.authorsWithPaginate)
);
}

authorEdit(id) {
    this.table.display = this.table.display === false;
    console.log('authorEdit:',id, this.table.display);
    return this.authors$;
  }

authorDelete(id) {
    this.table.display = this.table.display === false;
    console.log('authorDelete:',id, this.table.display);
    return this.authors$;
    }

onRowClicked(row) {
    console.log('Row clicked: ', row);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi there - a couple of clarifying questions. What changes in the query when you want it to update? And is onPageChanged getting called when these changes occur?

Comment: Hello there,
When I read your comment, I noticed you gave me a hint. Thank you for that. to change the variable values manually. The watch () function does not fire. I made a few changes in my code so I got the result.
The answer to the question you asked me was that the skip and limit variables did not change. The JavaScript world is very complex. I'm excited to learn.